Duplicated Points in Polygon_with_holes_2 result of a Minkowski_sum_2
When using CGAL to operate 'Minkwoski_sum_2' and produce 'no-fit-polygons', some polygons resulted with duplicate points. For example, taken from the terminal output (result of the 'print_polygon_with_holes()' function left in the usage examples):
NFP: 0 0 1 270
{ Outer boundary = [15 vertices: (6 5) (5 5) (3 4) (3 4) (1 5) (-1 4) (-1 1) (-1 -2) (0 -3) ( 2 -4) (4 -4) (6 -3) (8 -1) (8 1) (8 4)]
0 holes:
}
The procedure adopted in the orbiting polygon (the second polygon) is to invert (rotate 180 degrees) and apply it to the function.
Which is the result between two polygons: a) polygon 0 with rotation 0; b) polygon 1 with rotation at 270. (rotation in degrees, and again data printed in the terminal by the 'print_polygon()' function):
Item: 0 rotation: 0
[ 6 vertices: (0 0) (0 -3) (2 -4) (4 -3) (4 0) (2 1) ]
Item: 1 rotation: 270
[ 8 vertices: (0 0) (-2 0) (-4 -2) (-4 -4) (-3 -4) (-1 -3) (1 -4) (1 -1) ]
I'm using 'Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel', version 'Boost' 1.85, coordinates in 'FT' ('Field Type'), compiled with cmake version 3.29.6 and AppleClang 15.0
Has anyone else faced this situation?
To try to solve it, I have already tried using the 'erase()' function that exists in the 'Polygon_2' class. However, to no avail.

Could you share the input program used to generate the invalid output?

Resolved:
My academic advisor and I worked point by point on the resulting polygon, 'no-fit-polygon', looking for the repeating point removed from the polygon vector.
